# CSS - shrinking background div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I need to do the following:
[image]

The content from section two should overlap with section one  and section three.
I managed to move the content-div to one side, either I overlap section one or two with "position:relative" and a negative top/bottom value.

Is it somehow possible to shrink the background wrapper div but in the way, it's not affecting the inner wrapper content div ?

I simplified the image. The sections have angled pseudo elements (after and before). Don't know, if that matters.

With this code I manage to move my content-section to the bottom or top:

```
.site-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -100px;
}
```

But the main-section is still as high as the inner content is.

Comment: You can make it work using `margin` simply

Comment: Could you please share your code

Comment: I added one piece of the code. More is not needed as my code only moves the content to one site (top or bottom)

Comment: Add a container for them both add position absolute to your background div and relative to the main container. Reset positions so it covers, alter the size of the container to what you want and there done.

Comment: Could you please check if something like https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/qYNmpE is what you are looking for?

Comment: not quite. I need the sections in between fully accessible, as normal content elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) two `<div>` elements depending on the second section to not being affected by the container size:

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

div:first-child {
  top: -5vh;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  bottom: -5vh;
}
```

```html
<section>1</section>
<section>2
  <div>2.1</div>
  <div>2.2</div>
</section>
<section>3</section>
```

Comment: I need the content elements in "2" fully accesible like normal content elements. And this gap inbetween is my main problem.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Which gap do you mean exactly? Please edit your question to clarify your problem. Otherwise it will be closed as "too broad".

Comment: No, this is perfect like that. Sometimes its too easy! ;) Thank you!